# Taquito - Beacon connect dialog on iPhone does not show Temple Wallet option. How to solve it?

Tags: taquito, dapps, beacon, temple

I have a dApp that connects to wallets through Beacon, using Taquito. On PC Desktop computers and Android, the Beacon connect dialog window shows many wallet alternatives and also a blue generic button to choose which one to generally connect to. Nevertheless, specifically on iPhones, Temple Wallet option is not shown, neither this generic connect blue button. So, how do I connect (on iPhones) my dApp to Temple wallet using Taquito and Beacon?

I've read that on an iPhone it should be done the other way around: Connect Temple wallet to my dApp, but this requires my dApp to be listed inside Temple wallet. What's the correct way to solve this?

Comment: Are you aiming to pair your dApp with Temple Mobile or the Temple Browser Extension?

Comment: Hi, could you provide some more detail like the beacon-sdk version that is used or the website where the problem occurs?

Comment: I am aiming to pair my web dApp with Temple Mobile. This works on Android. However, on iPhone the Beacon dialog does not show Temple wallet option, neither the blue generic button.

Comment: It is still unclear what beacon-sdk/taquito version you use and which website that is - to try it out by myself for example. Without more technical details its not possible to give some clear guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Thank you very much for your time Jev Björsell and Ron.
I was really confusing things a little bit. First thing, you were right, the beacon cannot connect to a native application. Second thing is that, after upgrading libraries taquito, beacon and airgap, it has shown correctly the option to connect to Temple. Occurs that my system had gotten all messed up after I upgraded those dependencies as I use VueJS 3 that now ships with Vite (instead of webpack) and needed a lot of tweaking in configuration files (package.json, vite.config.js, index.html, etc). Claude Barde has helped me through the process and I finally got it working. I will write a Stack Exchange post about it to help others.